# NSXMLParser not reading all elements

Tags: ios, xml, swift, parsing, nsxmlparser

I need to parse a xml file which content can be found on this site: `http://jpg.tartu.ee/tunniplaan/xml/arvestus1.xml` ( In order to see this file you must look at the page source code! (The file is too big to post in here)

I first download this file and then my application reads the data in.

I am using `NSXMLParser`. From that file above I need element `TimeTableSchedule` attributes, but `NSXMLParser` does not find that element in the file, but it does exist.

I checked if it finds element named `TimeTableSchedule` with below code, but it does not! It prints out all the other elements except "TimeTableSchedule"

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
        print(elementName)
    }
```

My questions is: Why it does not find the element `TimeTableSchedule`? 
Is it something to do with that TimeTableSchedule element has two attributes called `Period`? Is there any way I can access `TimeTableSchedule` elements attributes using `NSXMLParser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that the XML is not well formed. It includes something like:

```
<TimeTableSchedule DayID="" Period="" Period="-1" SchoolRoomID="" SubjectGradeID="*28" ClassID="*11" OptionalClassID="" TeacherID=""/>
```

The attribute `Period` appears twice in that element. In fact, if you implemented `NSXMLParserDelegate` method `parseErrorOccurred` you would have seen an error to that effect. Or you can use the command line program `xmllint` to check the XML.

---

Given that you cannot fix the XML on the web service, you could theoretically fix it yourself in the client:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://jpg.tartu.ee/tunniplaan/xml/arvestus1.xml")!
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data where error == nil else {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    // replace occurrences of `Period="" Period` with `Period`

    let mutableData = data.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableData
    let searchData = "Period=\"\" Period".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let replacementData = "Period".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    var range = mutableData.rangeOfData(searchData, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: mutableData.length))
    while range.location != NSNotFound {
        mutableData.replaceBytesInRange(range, withBytes: replacementData.bytes, length: replacementData.length)
        range = mutableData.rangeOfData(searchData, options: [], range: NSRange(location: range.location, length: mutableData.length - range.location))
    }

    // now parse

    let parser = NSXMLParser(data: mutableData)
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()

    // do whatever you want with the parsed data here
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Hmm, okay, but any other ways to access that element using NSXMLParser or should I use another xml parser?

Comment: You either need to fix the XML or try another parser.

Comment: Can't change the source xml file, but thanks anyway.

Comment: That's too bad, as that's the best solution. You can replace occurrences of invalid XML, though. See revised answer.